# KnockoutJS observableArray not initialized

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Code

```
function Product(name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

function ProductViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.products = ko.observableArray();
  $.getJSON("/admin/test", function(allData) {
    var mappedProducts = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Product(item.name) });
    self.products(mappedProducts);
    console.log(self.products);
  });    
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
```

**Problem**: while `allData` and `mappedProducts` are properly set (just an array of products with name and some other field), the line `console.log(self.products);` is printing an empty array.

I am really confused, i am at first approach with KO but this seems the very same code from the tutorials... im just using products instead of tasks. I'm sure i'm missing something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should log the thing *inside* the observable instead of the observable itself:

```
console.log(self.products());
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGLmJ/) for a demo with your code in it.

In the question's situation it depends on the browser what will get logged. Granted, **Chrome** is somewhat confusing:

> `[]`

Seems like an empty array. **Internet Explorer 10** makes more sense, outputting:

> `function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.equalityComparer&&c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])||(c.K(),d=arguments[0],c.J()),this;a.q.bb(c);return d}`

That is: the fact that `self.products` is in fact a function (an observable). **Firefox** is in between, outputting:

> `c()`

Not as helpful as IE10, but not as confusing as Chrome either.

Answer (score 1):

This is for setting the observable :

```
self.products(mappedProducts)
```

And this is for getting the value of an observbale or a computed

```
var mappedProducts = self.products();
```

Notice the parenthesis.

I hope it helps.